# JSON.parse() error on string

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting an error when using JSON.parse()

```
$jsonStr = JSON.parse(["a:5:{i:0;s:4:"3900";i:1;s:4:"3892";i:2;s:4:"3896";i:3;s:4:"3894";i:4;s:4:"3902";}"])
```

I have used below, but what I need to do is get the content out, loop through it. I need to get 3900, 3892, 3896, 3894, 3902, those are ids, that I need to loop through them and attach to URL, I can attach to URL, I just need to loop through the string and get those ID's out. I don't have to use JSON.parse, I just need to use javascript.

`var jsonStr=$jsonStr;
 var json=JSON.stringify(jsonStr);
 json=JSON.parse(json)`

Comment: it's not valid json i would suggest you search google for JSON validator there are a million of them, they will point to where your JSON is fouled up.

Comment: The input does not resemble JSON. Is this a [PHP dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?

Comment: that's a serialized php structure. it's **NOT** json.

Comment: I am using a JSON-api plugin for wordpress, and this is what it spits out, the issue is, I cant use php for final product. I need to use javascript.

Comment: 1. That's not JSON, it's a PHP serialized array. 2. You are passing your serialized array inside a JavaScript array to `JSON.parse`, which makes no sense.

Comment: There even is a JS library to unserialize the data: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, your string is not valid Json.

If you still want to extract those strings out of it, you can use this:

```
var input = 'a:5:{i:0;s:4:"3900";i:1;s:4:"3892";i:2;s:4:"3896";i:3;s:4:"3894";i:4;s:4:"3902";}';

var matches = input.match(/:"[^"]*/g).join('').split(':"').slice(1);

// loop through the result:
matches.forEach(function (match) {
    console.log(match);
});
```

Output:

```
3900
3892
3896
3894
3902
```

Comment: Yes!!!!! Thank  you so much, that is exactly what I needed, and for it to loop.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't valid JSON. Try running it past something like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify that you have valid JSON. Remember: JSON is just a string which looks just like a standard object in Javascript but all of the keys *must* be quoted with double quotes.